# Is state the same thing as class variables and their values?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm struggling to understand the concept of state in Flutter. I'm coming from languages like Delphi, Python, and C#, and thinking:

- *everything is a widget* in Flutter is the same as *everything is an object* (class instance) in other languages
- a widget is an object inheriting from a class with a `build` method, analogous to classes with `OnPaint` or `OnShow` methods in other languages
- object properties (member variables) make up a widget/object's state. If there are no member variables or they are all declared as `const` or `final,` then the widget is stateless. If not then the properties and their values make up the widget/object's state.

What am I missing? What makes up state beside variables?

PS I get further confused when I read about Flutter elements and element trees, though [I may understand better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164817/what-is-an-element-in-flutter) once I've got a handle on widget state.

Comment: objects referred to by `final` names are modifiable

Comment: @RyanHaining Thanks, Ryan. I was assuming once a `final` variable had an initial value then it was no longer modifiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> object properties (member variables) make up a widget/object's state. If there are no member variables or theys are all declared as const or final, then the widget is stateless. If not then the properties and their values make up the widget/object's state.

This point is incorrect. `Widget`s are always immutable, but a `StatefulWidget` contains a reference to a [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) instance. States are where your mutable data is held. They have a much longer life than a typical widget, and include special state management methods such as `initState()`, `setState()`. They also have a `build()` method like widgets and for the most part seem like a widget, but they are actually a `State<Widget>`.

Should you use a StatelessWidget or a StatefulWidget? This question comes up a lot when starting Flutter development. My rule of thumb is that unless you know you really need a StatefulWidget, start with a stateless one. The reason being they are simpler and the most popular IDEs can convert a StatelessWidget to a StatefulWidget (and produce the corresponding State-extending class).

Comment: Thank you for responding, Jacob. This response is helpful. In fact, "They also have a `build()` method like widgets and for the most part seem like a widget" helps me understand better why I get confused!

Comment: Just to follow up to see if I understand, does this mean that when you call `setState()`, nothing happens to the `StatefulWidget` object, the `State<Widget>` object is freed or disposed, and a new instance of the `State<Widget>` class is then created? Is that how it works?

Comment: @AlC not exactly, `setState()` notifies the framework to rebuild that part of the tree, and results in the `build()` method being called again and updating the screen. The widget is built using the same instance of State, however.