# Elements vs Components in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Our team is planning on rewriting a mid sized app that was mostly in React. We are drawing a new architecture in Flutter. In this effort we are discussing proper terminology and how to classify different objects. In *React*, there is a meaningful difference between **Elements** and **Components**.

In the official Flutter documentation both words Elements and Components, are used for what -implicitly- seems to be different things https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material

> "Material Components widgets"
>
> "Expansion panels contain creation flows and allow lightweight editing of an element"

What are the difference between those two? In particular are *controllers, elements, states, images* considered as components?

Comment: Better start from https://flutter.dev/docs it will make you feel everything in flutter is a widget and that all UI is about there is something different cooking here so bettter forget previous terms and start afresh. Also read https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/react-native-devs

Comment: I do understand everything is a widget. I doubt that having one file called main.dart with all the widgets inside and surrounded by assets in the lib folder is a proper architecture though. But thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I think the "everything is a Widget" marketing phase is misleading. Not everything in Flutter is a Widget. Not even close.

Comment: `everything in flutter is a widget and that all UI is about`. In background we have routings, modals, etc.

Comment: Thanks for reminding on the  flutter.dev/docs - however when reading these I have a sense that while "widget" seems to be a clear notion, elements and components are used more liberally in official doc and even more liberally in popular additional plugins/imports. Thanks for the input was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "components" is vocabulary for Material Design. Components are design concepts. https://material.io/components/

"Widgets" are classes in Flutter.

Flutter widgets are often implementations of Material Design components.

Comment: Thanks - this answers the component part of my question. I made additional searches and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164817/what-is-an-element-in-flutter - putting them together, I have a sense now and can close it. Thank you

Comment: Did you see the following video about Widget tree, Element tree, and keys? https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: I came across this resource recently - it gives a quite extensive answer to my original question. https://www.flutterinternals.org/data-model/elements

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from comment. Break your folder structure like

```
|--ui
   |--login
   |--home
   |-- ......
|--modal
|--rest
|--routes
|--helpers
```

etc as per your convenience. Also make custom widgets which are to be used everywhere combining other simpler widgets and can put in helper folder.

Also look at other opensource flutter projects. You will get a better idea how everyone else are grouping things.